# How to set up Git source control for matlab?

Tags: git, matlab, github

This is the first time I'm using Github. I want to use it as a tool for sharing code and organizing the different versions of my code.
I've downloaded [Git for Windows](http://git-scm.com/download/win) and installed. I've also installed [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) as the GUI client. I'm studying [ProGit book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) and [GitHub Desktop Documentation](https://help.github.com/desktop/) to start.
Recently I'm coding with MATLAB for my thesis. So as the first step, I've started with [Select or Disable Source Control System](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/select-or-disable-source-control-system.html). But when I go to `MATLAB > General > Source Control`, there's only one option and that is none.
[image]

**What should I do?**

---

Edit:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would need to [setup Git first with matlab](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-up-git-source-control.html).

That involves:

- uncompressing the [latest git archive](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) anywhere you want (like [`PortableGit-2.7.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.7.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.7.0-64-bit.7z.exe) uncompressed in `c:\PortableGit-2.7.0-64-bit`.
- add `c:\PortableGit-2.7.0-64-bit;c:\PortableGit-2.7.0-64-bit\bin;c:\PortableGit-2.7.0-64-bit\usr\bin` to your `%PATH%`.
- define the environment variable `HOME` to `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`
- launch matlab in a CMD session where `PATH` does reflect the paths mentioned above, and where `HOME` is set.

Typically, create a small senv.bat script with (assuming you did install git as I specified):

```
@echo off
set PATH=C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

set GIT_ROOT=c:\PortableGit-2.7.0-64-bit
set PATH=%PATH%;%GIT_ROOT%;%GIT_ROOT%\cmd;%GIT_ROOT%\bin;%GIT_ROOT%\usr\bin"

set "MATLAB_ROOT=C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b"
set PATH=%PATH%;%MATLAB_ROOT%;%MATLAB_ROOT%\bin;%MATLAB_ROOT%\runtime\win64;%MATLAB_ROOT%\polyspace\bin;
```

Open a CMD session, go to the folder where you put `senv.bat`, type `senv.bat`, then launch MATLAB from the same command line (I don't know the name of the MATLAB exe)

Comment: I've done this step already during the installation of [64-bit Git for Windows Setup](http://git-scm.com/download/win). In fact I first read the page [Set Up Git Source Control](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-up-git-source-control.html) and then the page [Select or Disable Source Control System](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/select-or-disable-source-control-system.html)

Comment: @sepideh then check your `%PATH%` and `%HOME%` in a `CMD` session. Does `git --version` works there? If yes, launch matlab from there.

Comment: how should I do that?

Comment: There's this. I've added a photo of launching matlab from the command prompt. But I don't know it's right or not. In fact I'm not familiar a lot with working through the system's command prompt. A bad habit for windows users

Comment: @sepideh to check path or home, type `set PATH` and `set HOME`

Comment: OK I've done and added the photo. What does that list of paths mean? what should I do?

Comment: @sepideh it means your PATH is way too long ;) I'll edit the answer

Comment: OK, I'll add another question and I will explain my way of installation step by step to see what's going wrong

Comment: @sepideh Great. Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer and http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: I will as soon as the problem gets fixed. I'll link the two questions together to help future questionnaires who have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot which you shared tells me that you are running a MATLAB version prior to R2014b; those simply did not have Git integration yet. This was added in the R2014b release, see:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015b/matlab/release-notes.html#buikqh_-1

In those older releases MATLAB only supported MSSCCI compatible source control systems; I do not believe there is a MSSCCI compatible interface for Git.

In newer releases your preferences would show "Enable MathWorks source control integration" and that would then support Git (which might then require the further setup as from the other Answer).