# What's wrong with my installation process of Git to set it up for matlab?

Tags: git, matlab, github

Based on the answer that I received [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34893780/1245120) and what is written [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-up-git-source-control.html#buhx2d6-1_1), I've done the following steps:

1. I've downloaded [Git-2.7.0-64-bit.exe](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) and ran it:
   [image]
2. After completing the set up wizard, based on what is told [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-up-git-source-control.html#buhx2d6-1_3), because I don't know what's the purpose of sandbox folder, I've created a `.gitattributes` file using matlab command prompt:

   ```
   edit .gitattributes
   ```

and added the following text to the file:

```
*.mat -crlf -diff -merge
*.p -crlf -diff -merge
*.slx -crlf -diff -merge
*.mdl -crlf -diff -merge
*.mdlp -crlf -diff -merge
*.slxp -crlf -diff -merge
*.sldd -crlf -diff -merge
*.mexa64 -crlf -diff -merge
*.mexw32 -crlf -diff -merge
*.mexw64 -crlf -diff -merge
*.mexmaci64 -crlf -diff -merge
*.xlsx -crlf -diff -merge
*.docx -crlf -diff -merge
*.pdf -crlf -diff -merge
*.jpg -crlf -diff -merge
*.png -crlf -diff -merge
```

then closed MATLAB.

3. I've created a t.bat file in the directory `C:\Users\sepideh\Desktop\test` named it `senv.bat` and typed the following code in it:

```
set PATH=C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GIT_ROOT=C:\Program Files\Git
set PATH=%PATH%;%GIT_ROOT%;%GIT_ROOT%\cmd;%GIT_ROOT%\bin;%GIT_ROOT%\usr\bin
set MATLAB_ROOT=C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b
set PATH=%PATH%;%MATLAB_ROOT%;%MATLAB_ROOT%\bin;%MATLAB_ROOT%\runtime\win64;%MATLAB_ROOT%\polyspace\bin;
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\sepideh\Documents\MATLAB
```

[image]

4. I've started a system command prompt and typed:
   [image]

**Matlab launches but the main problem still exists**
[image]

Comment: "But I don't know where is the file senv.bat to continue." - referenced here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892960/how-to-set-up-git-source-control-for-matlab/34893780#34893780 -- it's just the name of the file where you *s*et the *env*ironment variables. As you have done it directly on the command line you should be fine.

Comment: I'm really confused. [the problem of just having none still exists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34892960/1245120). I'm just searching for a way to use Github with programming IDEs easily

Comment: What version of MATLAB

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but did you restart MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch `MATLAB.exe` in the same `CMD` session you set `PATH` and `HOME`.

If you open a new one, it will not inherit your previous setup;

Comment: @sepideh could you try the portable one, as detailed in the answer?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101311/discussion-on-answer-by-vonc-whats-wrong-with-my-installation-process-of-git-to).

Comment: It's not just for you, it's for the OP too;  clarifying information should be edited into your answer; and they should edit their clarifying information into their answer.